# ¿como soluciono problemas con paginacion en laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo un query con laravel, y al momento de paginar, me sale un error que dice - El metodo paginar no existe (Method paginate does not exist.)

por un lado en el controlador, llamo al query y pagino de la siguiente manera:

```
$img_ventass = Img_venta::busqueda($request->get('raza_id'), $request->get('sexo'), $request->get('fecha_nacimiento'))->paginate(4);
```

y por otra parte, realizo el query en el modelo asi:

```
public function scopeBusqueda($query, $raza_id, $sexo, $fecha_nacimiento){
    return $query->leftJoin('ventas', function ($leftJoin) use ($raza_id, $sexo) {
        $leftJoin->on('img_ventas.venta_id', '=', 'ventas.id')
             ->where('ventas.raza_id', '=', $raza_id)
             ->where('ventas.sexo', '=', $sexo);
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tienes es que estás llamando al método `get()` dentro del scope, lo cual no te permite:

- hacer consultas anidadas después de llamar a dicho scope.
- Utilizar otros métodos de filtrado o selección como `first()` o `paginate()`.

La solución es quitar el método get() del scope:

```
public function scopeBusqueda($query, $raza_id, $sexo, $fecha_nacimiento){
    return $query->leftJoin('ventas', function ($leftJoin) use ($raza_id, $sexo) {
        $leftJoin->on('img_ventas.venta_id', '=', 'ventas.id')
             ->where('ventas.raza_id', '=', $raza_id)
             ->where('ventas.sexo', '=', $sexo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Entonces puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada y formular una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Super bien, el error se soluciono. Lamentablemente me surgió un nuevo problema y por mas que investigue, revise, mire foros, no logro resolverlo y de seguro debe ser algo "sencillo".  El nuevo error es que cuando paso a la siguiente pagina, 2,3,4,etc, la nueva pagina aparece en blanco. :s

Comment: Estás usando page como parámetro en la url?

Comment: no: mira, por un lado tengo la ruta que me lleva al controlador donde realizo la consula:  Route::get('/result', 'BuscadorController@create');                    por otro tengo una de tantas consultas(el error pasa con todas las consultas) $img = img_adopcion::paginate(3);                 y en la vista donde tengo el formulario para las diferentes combinaciones para la consulta(opciones de filtro) lo tengo asi: {!! Form::open(['url' => 'result', 'method' => 'GET']) !!} el realiza la consulta pagina y muestra los resultados de la primera pagina y los ordena, pero al ir a cualquier otra pag. nad

Comment: qué pasa si regresas por medio de la navegación de la página 2 a la 1... también se muestran los resultados?

Comment: igual, en blanco como las demás.

Comment: Puedes copiar la url exacta cuando estás en esa primera página, regresando de la página 2?

Comment: cuando realizo la consulta, me pasa todos los parametros http://localhost:8000/result?categoria=1&tama%C3%B1o=seleccionar&edad=&precio=seleccionar&raza_id=&ubicacion=seleccionar&sexo=

Comment: al pasar a la siguiente pagina, solo pagina:   http://localhost:8000/result?page=2

Comment: -http://localhost:8000/result?page=1-   y al regresar a la pagina 1 esta seria la url sin todos los parámetros, de inmediato detecto que el error esta ahí, pero no se por que me pasa todos los  parámetros de esa forma